# How to store and verify PIN code

Tags: database, security, authentication, encryption, hash

I am developing a scratch-card voucher pin application

1. The 12 digit pin will be generated by pseudo-random tool
2. The pin (and a serialno) is tored in the database for authentication
3. User type in the pin to use a service, and the pin is checked against the database for verification by scanning through the Pin Column
4. The pin should also be decoded (in rare cases)

Problem
If the pin is encrypted, it will be difficult query the database for the verification. Since the search is based on pin.
How do i store the pin code so that

1. It can be unique, and matched during verification

Comment: Please explain why it is difficult if the pin is encrypted..

Comment: if the pin encrypted, i cant search the database based on the encrypted value, because most of the encryption does not return the exact value when repeated, unlike Hashing
Trying to decrypt all the rows before comparing the value will be inefficient and takes long when done in a table of about 200,000 rows

Comment: How about saving the encrypted value instead of saving the real value.. So encrypt the inserted value first, before comparing the inserted pin with the db.. I'm not an expert in encryption but if you use something like SHA/DES it will return the exact value when repeated, if only you use the same key..

Answer (score -1):

Just encrypt the pin and store it. When the user enters the pin for verification, encrypt it also and compare the encrypted stored pin with the encrypted user-entered pin. If you need to decode pin in rare cases, use a decodable encryption. I would recommend not doing so and forcing the user to update to a new pin if he loses or forgets the old one.

Comment: This answer has messed up terms (encryption/decryption-encoding/decoding-hashing), and should not be taken as a reference.